# how to check : dateOne < dateTwo

Tags: java, validation, datetime, calendar

I need help to check following conditions related to date and time...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

String CurrentDate= dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

**String ModifiedDate = dateTime taken from date n time picker widget ;**

i have to check :

**current ModifiedDate is not less than 5 minutes of current time**

How to check this conditon in Android / Java..........?

Comment: This can help you http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/small-code-stuffs-used-for-validations-in-java-or-android/  (check implementation of `Check date is of Future`)

Comment: This is not about `android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you *formatting* the date?

It's much easier to work with data in a "natural" representation rather than in a string representation. It's not clear whether your modified date *has* to be taken as a string, but if it does, the first thing you should do is *parse* it. You can then compare that with the current date and time using:

```
// Check if the value is later than "now"
if (date.getTime() > System.currentTimeMillis())
```

or

```
// Check if the value is later than "now + 5 minutes"
if (date.getTime() > System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
```

It's not really clear what you mean by "current ModifiedDate is not less than 5 minutes of current time" - whether you mean that it's not less than 5 minutes after, or not less than 5 minutes earlier, or something like that - but you should be able to change the code above to handle your requirements.

If you do a lot of date/time manipulation, I'd *strongly* recommend the use of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), which is a much better date/time API than `java.util.Date`/`Calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the given time is before/after the current time ,
There is a Calendar instance in Android...to compare date time values.

```
Calendar current_time = Calendar.getInstance ();

current_time.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);

current_time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrs);

current_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mins );

current_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


Calendar given_time = Calendar.getInstance ();

given_time.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);

given_time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hrs);

given_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mins );

given_time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


current_time.getTime();

given_time.getTime();


boolean v = current_calendar.after(given_calendar);


// it will return true if current time is after given time


if(v){

return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean getTimeDiff(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo) {
    long timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
    int day =   (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff);
    int min=    (int) ( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff)));
    if(day>1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(min>5)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
System.out.println(getTimeDiff(new Date("01/13/2012 12:05:00"),new Date("01/12/2012 13:00:00")));
```